# Count values from a concatenated column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, concatenation

I'm running this query, but I'm getting and error when I add count

```
SELECT 
CONCAT (product_code, product_color) AS new_product_code
FROM [dbo].[Furniture]
where product = 'couch'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfefl.png)

I would like to add another column and be able to count how many times a product was purchased according to its color. But I want to keep the product_code and product_color concatenated in a column. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Please do not use images for data, code or errors - use formatting/tabular text.

Comment: And please provide sample data and desired results. Ideally provide your sample data as DDL+DML so we can consume it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect when you added `count()`, you didn't have the `GROUP BY`

The traditional approach

```
Select Prod_Color = CONCAT(product_code, product_color )
      ,count(*)
 From  [dbo].[Furniture]
 Where product = 'couch'
 Group By CONCAT(product_code, product_color )
```

Or using a `CROSS APPLY` for a single expression

```
Select Prod_Color 
      ,count(*)
 From [dbo].[Furniture]
 Cross Apply ( values ( CONCAT(product_code, product_color ) ) ) V(Prod_Color)
 Where product = 'couch'
 Group By Prod_Color
```

Comment: Shouldn't WHERE come before GROUP BY?

Comment: @tinazmu  Yup...   I added the WHERE after the fact and without thinking  ... Thanks for the catch